# Solid volume of a cone with triple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

The question: the solid in the first octant bounded by the cone $$z=1-{\sqrt{{x^2}+{y^2}}}$$ and the plane $$z+y+x=1$$ Find the volume.

I tried multiple different orders but got different answers. I'd appreciate if you can get me thru the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Since for $x,y\geq 0$ with $x^2+y^2\leq 1$, 
$$1-{\sqrt{{x^2}+{y^2}}}\geq 1-x-y,$$
it follows that the solid is given by the cone intersected the first octant minus the tetrahedron of vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1)$. Therefore
$$\mbox{Volume}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{1/2}{3}=\frac{\pi-2}{12}.$$
To obtain the same result by using integration, compute
$$\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{1-x}\int_{z=1-x-y}^{1-{\sqrt{{x^2}+{y^2}}}}dz dy dx+\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=1-x}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{z=0}^{1-{\sqrt{{x^2}+{y^2}}}}dz dy dx\\
=\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{z=0}^{1-{\sqrt{{x^2}+{y^2}}}}dz dy dx-\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{1-x}\int_0^{z=1-x-y}dz dy dx\\
=\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int_{\rho=0}^{1}\int_{z=0}^{1-\rho}dz \rho d\rho d\theta-\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^{1-x}\int_0^{z=1-x-y}dz dy dx\\
=\frac{\pi}{12}-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{\pi-2}{12}$$

Comment: I got 0.09513 which is the same answer. I did subtract the right triangular prism, too. Basically, I used triple integrals for the big cone and another triple integral set for the right triangular prism. I'm wonder if there's a way without subtracting the right triangular prism.

Comment: @turbokick4.0 I think that this is the best way to do it.